# How to pass Datagridview data in Stimulsoft using VB.NET 2008?

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview, stimulsoft

I am creating a small program using VB.NET 2008, Stimulsoft Report Generator and MySQL as database,

How can I pass the data of DataGridview in Stilmusoft Report when I click the print button. Please help me.

Comment: what have you done so far?

Comment: @MAC I have a form Sir loading the datagridview data automatically when call that form and I have also a Report.mrt, it shows when I click the print button. Here is my code on load the report. Dim Report As StiReport = New StiReport()
Report.Load("report.mrt")
Report.Show()

Answer (score -1):

It's depended to your code. You can pass data from database to a dataSet and send It to report.
You can use this document:
http://admin.stimulsoft.com/documentation/Stimulsoft_Reports.Net_FAQ.En.pdf

Comment: Thank you sir, I have read your link suggestion but I don't know how to work with the stimulsoft designer regarding on the variables and parameters.